# (C++) Is creating a class/object specifically for handling all other custom objects a proper way to handle a project?

Tags: c++

I asked a question yesterday, but it seems I did ask it incorrectly, so here I go again. I quickly mocked up this code, and I'm wondering if this is a proper way to handle the objects (outside of just putting everything in `main()`. This would be my first time trying to complete a larger project, so I've never had a need to question how to contain and handle the objects.

skill.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

class Skill;

typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Skill>> SkillVector;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Skill>> SkillMap;

class Skill {
private:
    std::string _skill_name;
    std::string _skill_description;
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Skill& skill);
    void print(std::ostream& stream) const;

public:
    Skill(const std::string& skill_name, const std::string& skill_description);
    const std::string& getSkillName() const;
    const std::string& getSkillDescription() const;
    bool isMatch(const std::string& substring) const;
};
```

application.h

```
#pragma once

#include "skill.h"

extern std::string SKILL_FILE;

class Application {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<SkillMap> _skill_map;
    void loadData();
    void loadSkills();
    void printSkillMap();
    void printSkillVector(const SkillVector& skills);
    std::unique_ptr<SkillVector> skillSearch(const std::string& input) const;
public:
    Application();
    void run();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "application.h"

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Application> application(new Application);
    application->run();

    return 0;
}
```

This is going to be a command-line application, so other than this I can't think of doing anything else except putting all the methods from the application class straight into main as regular functions. That doesn't seem like the correct approach though. I've tried researching this pretty extensively, but haven't really found anything that answers this.

What are the other options for containing all the objects in an orderly fashion? What are the advantages of doing it certain ways? And is what I'm doing here acceptable?

NOTE: This isn't an exact representation of my project, and I'm just using it as an example to understand my question at hand.

Comment: There is no best way to do this, but you might want to look for information on [design patterns](https://www.developer.com/design/overview-of-design-patterns-for-beginners.html) 
specifically for games you can read [this](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html). Look up more information by yourself about the topic it will sure come in handy. Once you have a punctual problem we will be able to help gladly.

Comment: It actually isn't for a game, but I'll give it a look nonetheless.

Comment: I get the impression that you might have tried Java earlier. :-)  You don't *have to* put all functions inside a class. You don't *have to* create an object using `new` and don't *have to* use a `unique_ptr` is you are not going to transfer ownership, ever.

Comment: You should remove the "skill" part of all field, parameter, and method names in the `Skill` class. They're redundant, adding noise. The exception to this is instances of `Skill` such as `const Skill& skill`.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** There isn't a single answer on how to move forward. It depends on:

1. What your goal is.
2. What subsystems the project will have, and how they integrate with one another.
3. The type and quantity of data that the project will require.

That said, it's almost always a good idea to apply [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), segregating data & functionality between types that correspond to each of your project's concerns. Here's an example using a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to get you started:

```
// Note that this example uses C++11 features.
// Note that the stubs are intentional, to keep this example as terse as possible.

// For consistency with your naming style.
typedef std::string String;
template<typename T>
using Vector = std::vector<T>;
template<typename T>
using UniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T>;

// Skill.hpp: Represents a single skill.
class Skill {
private:
    String _name;
    String _description;

public:
    Skill(String name, String description);

    const String& getName() const { return _name; }
    const String& getDescription() const { return _description; }
};

// Player.hpp: Represents a single player.
class Player {
private:
    Vector<Skill*> _skills;
    bool _isVirtual; // Is this player from another computer? (networked multiplayer)

public:
    Player(bool isVirtual = false) :
        _skills(),
        _isVirtual(isVirtual) {}
    Player(const Player& other) = delete; // Non-copyable.

    bool hasSkill(Skill* skill) const;
    void addSkill(Skill* skill);
    bool removeSkill(Skill* skill); // Returns true if removed, false otherwise.
    bool isVirtual() const { return _isVirtual; }
};

// Level.hpp: Represents a single level of the game.
class Level {
private:
    // Per-level data...

public:
    Level();
    Level(const Level& other) = delete; // Non-copyable.
};

// GameState.hpp: Represents the state of the game.
enum class GameState {
    MainMenu,   // The user is in the main menu.
    World,      // The user is navigating the world.
    Combat,     // The user is in combat.
};

// Game.hpp: Represents a single game instance.
class Game {
private:
    Application* _app;
    Vector<UniquePtr<Player>> _players;
    Vector<UniquePtr<Level>> _levels;
    Level* _level; // Current level the player(s) are on.
    GameState _state; // Current state of the game.
    bool _isRunning; // Is the game running?

    void mainMenuLoop() {
        while (_isRunning) {
            // Implement your main menu here.
            // Update the menu display after user input.

            // When a selection is confirmed, execute it and return.
        }
    }
    void combatLoop() {
        while (_isRunning) {
            // Implement your combat system here. 

            // When combat is over, update _state and return.
        }
    }

public:
    Game(Application* app) :
        _app(app),
        _players(),
        _levels(),
        _level(),
        _state(GameState::MainMenu),
        _isRunning(true) { 
        // Finish initializing and:
        // If loading is fast enough, do so here.
        // If loading is slow, spin up a thread and load asynchronously.
    }
    Game(const Game& other) = delete; // Non-copyable.

    void run() {
        // If loading is slow, wait on the loading thread to complete.

        // Possibly show an introduction banner.
        while (_isRunning) {
            switch (_state) {
                case GameState::MainMenu: 
                    mainMenuLoop();
                    break;
                case GameState::Combat:
                    combatLoop();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    void quit() { _isRunning = false; }
    const Player* getPlayer(int index) const;
    Player* getPlayer(int index);
    void addPlayer(Player* player);
    bool removePlayer(Player* player); // Returns true if removed, false otherwise.
    const Level* getLevel(int index) const;
    Level* getLevel(int index);
    void addLevel(Level* level);
    bool removeLevel(Level* level); // Returns true if removed, false otherwise.
};

// Options.hpp: Represents command line options.
struct Options {
    // Add your command line options here.

    Options();
    Options(const Options& other);
};

// Application.hpp: Represents a single application instance.
class Application {
private:
    Options _options;
    Game _game;

public:
    // For compatibility with your code.
    Application() :
        _options(),
        _game(this) {}
    // For later, when you add command line options.
    Application(const Options& options) :
        _options(options),
        _game(this) {}
    Application(const Application& other) = delete; // Non-copyable.

    const Options& getOptions() const { return _options; }
    const Game* getGame() const { return &_game; }
    Game* getGame() { return &_game; }
    // For compatibility with your code. You could 
    // remove this and directly use getGame()->run()
    void run() { _game.run(); }
};
```

In `main` using `unique_ptr` for the `Application` object is unnecessary. Use the stack instead:

```
// Added arguments because you'll probably want command-line options later.
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Application app; // Better locality, no dynamic allocation.
    app.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! While I'm not actually making a game, this actually has helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following rules:

- When you have inheritance, the classes should respond to 'is-a'. For example if you have `class Speed : public Skill`. That seems logical and: Speed is a Skill.
- When you have composition, the classes should respond to 'has-a'. In your case: Application has a Skill map. 
  If the class was **Hero** it would be really logical: Hero has a Skill map. And this hero will develop the skills also the hero might need to print its skills... So the Hero will manage his Skills.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.